# GeoCoding GetLocationAsync method return KLCErrorDomain Code = 8 error for specific address in Xamarin Forms IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, geocoding, xamarin.essentials

GeoCoding GetLocationAsync method return 'KLCErrorDomain Code=8' error for specific address in Xamarin Forms IOS. same address is working in android but IOS only getting error. Here I have tried with below address. Here I have used Xamarin.Essentials Nuget is used for GeoCoding api.

Address: SAINT PETERSBURG, SPE, RU

Below code I have tried for getting position based on address

```
  var locations = await Geocoding.GetLocationsAsync(address);
  var location = locations?.FirstOrDefault();

  if (location != null)
  {
     return new double[] { location.Latitude, location.Longitude };
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61482244/4984832

Comment: Thank you for your response. In my project I am getting location address with country code only. so is there any alternative to get position based address with country code.

Comment: Could you provide the code for us to test?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have update question with code. Can you please check once.

Comment: The code is okay. I have checked it with the adress `Microsoft Building 25 Redmond WA USA`. It would return the correct location. Please check the address you provided again. I was able to reproduce the same with the address you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Only specific address and IOS device only above code doesn't return data. for example 'AD DAMMAM, SA' this address getting exception in IOS device but android device working fine.